# Вывод связанных элементов фильтра с другого инфоблока

Tags: php, битрикс

У нас есть товар - деталь машины (инфоблок Торговый каталог). 
Содержит артикул, бренд, машина, группа, к которой принадлежит данная деталь .
У него есть свойство привязки "машина" к другому инфоблоку Машины (торговый каталог) по xml_id,
содержит свойства марка, модель, тип кузова, год выпуска. 
Задача: сделать умный фильтр по полям-свойствам машины +группе , к которой принадлежит деталька. 
Итак, вот пытаюсь делать сначала Фильтр по полям марка, модель, год выпуска.

```html
global $arFilt;?> 
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:catalog.smart.filter", "uni_auto_smart_filter", Array(
 "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "1c_auto", // Тип инфоблока
 "IBLOCK_ID" => "7", // Инфоблок
 "SECTION_ID" => "", // ID раздела инфоблока
 "SECTION_CODE" => "",
 "FILTER_NAME" => "arFilter", // Имя выходящего массива для фильтрации
 "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "N",
 "TEMPLATE_THEME" => "blue",
 "FILTER_VIEW_MODE" => "vertical",
 "DISPLAY_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "Y",
 "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
 "CACHE_TYPE" => "A", // Тип кеширования
 "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000", // Время кеширования (сек.)
 "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y", // Учитывать права доступа
 "SAVE_IN_SESSION" => "N", // Сохранять установки фильтра в сессии пользователя
 "INSTANT_RELOAD" => "Y", // Мгновенная фильтрация при включенном AJAX
 "PAGER_PARAMS_NAME" => "arrPager",
 "PRICE_CODE" => array( // Тип цены
            '1'=>'zakupochnye',
 ),
 "CONVERT_CURRENCY" => "Y",
 "XML_EXPORT" => "N",
 "SECTION_TITLE" => "-",
 "SECTION_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
 "POPUP_POSITION" => "bottom",
 "SECTION_CODE_PATH" => "",
 "SMART_FILTER_PATH" => $_REQUEST["SMART_FILTER_PATH"],
 "CURRENCY_ID" => "RUB"
 ),
 false
);?>
<?// мы получили фильтр, туда передали значения.$arFilter;
$arFilr=array("IBLOCK_ID"=>7);
$arSelect = Array("XML_ID");
$res1c=CIBlockElement::GetList(array(),array_merge($arFilter,$arFilr),false,array(),$arSelect);  
while($ar_fields = $res1c->GetNext()){
    $arrayMas[]=array("LOGIC" => "AND",array("=PROPERTY_736.XML_ID"=>$ar_fields['XML_ID'],"=PROPERTY_736.IBLOCK_ID"=>7));
}
$arFilt[]=array($arrayMas);
print_r($arFilt);


?>
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:catalog.link.list","",
Array(
        "AJAX_MODE" => "Y",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "1c_catalog",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "1",
        "LINK_PROPERTY_SID" => "",
        "ELEMENT_ID" => $_REQUEST["PARENT_ELEMENT_ID"],
        "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => "sort",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => "asc",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD2" => "id",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc",
        "FILTER_NAME" => "arFilter",
        "SECTION_URL" => "",
        "DETAIL_URL" => "",
        "BASKET_URL" => "/personal/basket.php",
        "ACTION_VARIABLE" => "action",
        "PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE" => "id",
        "SECTION_ID_VARIABLE" => "SECTION_ID",
        "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
        "PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "30",
        "PROPERTY_CODE" => array(),
        "PRICE_CODE" => array(),
        "USE_PRICE_COUNT" => "N",
        "SHOW_PRICE_COUNT" => "1",
        "PRICE_VAT_INCLUDE" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "300",
        "CACHE_FILTER" => "Y",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
        "PAGER_TITLE" => "Товары",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "Y",
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "Y",
        "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "N",
        "CONVERT_CURRENCY" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "Y",
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
        "PRODUCT_DISPLAY_MODE" => "Y",
        "TEMPLATE_THEME" => "blue",
        "SHOW_DISCOUNT_PERCENT" => "N",
        "SHOW_OLD_PRICE" => "N",
        "SHOW_CLOSE_POPUP" => "N",
        "MESS_BTN_BUY" => "Купить",
        "MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET" => "В корзину",
        "MESS_BTN_DETAIL" => "Подробнее",
        "MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "Нет в наличии",
        "ADD_PICT_PROP" => "-",
        "LABEL_PROP" => "-",
        "PRODUCT_DISPLAY_MODE" => "N",
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "Y",
        "ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION" => "ADD"
    )
);?>
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:catalog.section", "uni_catalog_section_filter", array(
     "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "1c_catalog",
     "IBLOCK_ID" => "1",
     "SECTION_ID" => "",
     "SECTION_CODE" => "",
     "SECTION_USER_FIELDS" => array(
      0 => "",
      1 => "",
     ),
     "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => "sort",
     "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => "desc",
     "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD2" => "id",
     "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc",
     "FILTER_NAME" => "arFilt",
     "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
     "SHOW_ALL_WO_SECTION" => "Y",
     "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "N",
     "PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "30",
     "LINE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "1",
     "PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
      0 => "BREND",
      1 => "CML2_ARTICLE",
      2 => "DNEY_DOSTAVKI",
      3 => "",
     ),
     "OFFERS_FIELD_CODE" => array(
      0 => "ID",
      1 => "",
     ),
     "OFFERS_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
      0 => "CML2_LINK",
      1 => "",
     ),
     "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD" => '',
     "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER" =>'' ,
     "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD2" => "",
     "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER2" => "",
     "OFFERS_LIMIT" => "30",
     "SECTION_URL" => "",
     "DETAIL_URL" => "",
     "BASKET_URL" => "/personal/cart/",
     "ACTION_VARIABLE" => "action",
     "PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE" => "id",
     "PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE" => "quantity",
     "PRODUCT_PROPS_VARIABLE" => "prop",
     "SECTION_ID_VARIABLE" => "SECTION_ID",
     "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
     "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
     "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "N",
     "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
     "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
     "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
     "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
     "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
     "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
     "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
     "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
     "DISPLAY_COMPARE" => "N",
     "SET_TITLE" => "N",
     "SET_STATUS_404" => "Y",
     "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
     "USE_PRICE_COUNT" => "N",
     "SHOW_PRICE_COUNT" => "1",
     "PRICE_VAT_INCLUDE" => "Y",
     "PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => array(
     ),
     "USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY" => "N",
     "CONVERT_CURRENCY" => "N",
     "OFFERS_CART_PROPERTIES" => array(
     ),
     "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => ""
     ),
     false
    );?>
```

почему то выводятся все товары, которые есть, а не товары , принадлежащие машинам, указанных в фильтре. что-то не так? фильтр неверный.

UPD
Подумала  над словами Никольского и переписала запрос гетлиста

```html
$arFilr=array("IBLOCK_ID"=>7);
$arSelect = Array("XML_ID");
$res1c=CIBlockElement::GetList(array(),array_merge($arFilter,$arFilr),false,array(),$arSelect); 
$arrayMas = array("LOGIC" => "OR");
while($ar_fields = $res1c->GetNext()){
    $arrayMas[]=array("LOGIC" => "AND",array("=PROPERTY_736_VALUE"=>$ar_fields['XML_ID'],"=IBLOCK_ID"=>7));
}
$arFilt[]=array($arrayMas);
print_r($arFilt);
```

Получается:
`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [LOGIC] => OR [0] => Array ( [LOGIC] => AND [0] => Array ( [=PROPERTY_736_VALUE] => 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111 [=IBLOCK_ID] => 7 ) ) [1] => Array ( [LOGIC] => AND [0] => Array ( [=PROPERTY_736_VALUE] => 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111112 [=IBLOCK_ID] => 7 ) ) ) ) )`

Попробовала другой запрос

```html
$res1c=CIBlockElement::GetList(array(),array_merge($arFilter,$arFilr),false,array(),$arSelect);
$subQ=array("LOGIC"=>"OR");
while($ar_fields = $res1c->GetNext()){
    $subQ[]=array("ID"=>CIBlockElement::SubQuery("ID", array(
                "IBLOCK_ID" => 7,
                "PROPERTY_CML2_AUTO" =>array($ar_fields['XML_ID']),
              ))
        );
}
$arFilt[]=array($subQ);
print_r($arFilt);
```

Получается 
`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [LOGIC] => OR [0] => Array ( [LOGIC] => AND [0] => Array ( [=PROPERTY_736_VALUE] => 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111 [=IBLOCK_ID] => 7 ) ) [1] => Array ( [LOGIC] => AND [0] => Array ( [=PROPERTY_736_VALUE] => 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111112 [=IBLOCK_ID] => 7 ) ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [LOGIC] => OR [0] => Array ( [ID] => CIBlockElement Object ( [LAST_ERROR] => [bWF_SetMove:protected] => 1 [strField:protected] => ID [subQueryProp:protected] => [arFilter:protected] => Array ( [IBLOCK_ID] => 7 [PROPERTY_CML2_AUTO] => Array ( [0] => 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111 ) ) [sFrom:protected] => [sWhere:protected] => ) ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => CIBlockElement Object ( [LAST_ERROR] => [bWF_SetMove:protected] => 1 [strField:protected] => ID [subQueryProp:protected] => [arFilter:protected] => Array ( [IBLOCK_ID] => 7 [PROPERTY_CML2_AUTO] => Array ( [0] => 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111112 ) ) [sFrom:protected] => [sWhere:protected] => ) ) ) ) )`
фильтр неправильно работает- выдает все товары.

После установленного фильтра Никольского, выдает то же самое.

```html
$arrayMas = array("LOGIC" => "OR"); while($ar_fields = $res1c->GetNext()){ $arrayMas[]=array("=PROPERTY_736_VALUE"=>$ar_fields['XML_ID'],"=IBLOCK_ID"=>7); }
$arFilt=$arrayMas;
```

```html
      

Array
(
    [LOGIC] => OR
    [0] => Array
        (
            [=PROPERTY_736_VALUE] => 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
            [=IBLOCK_ID] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [=PROPERTY_736_VALUE] => 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111112
            [=IBLOCK_ID] => 7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [=PROPERTY_736_VALUE] => 2222222222222222222222
            [=IBLOCK_ID] => 7
        )

)
```

Comment: А почему `$arFilter` берется ниоткуда?

Comment: Он берется из фильтра умного, первая компонента. Массив формируется с помощью `GetList`, но неправильно.- так как плохо передается в компоненту `catalog.section`

Comment: $arElement = CIBlockElement::GetProperty(1, 2456613, Array("sort"=>"asc"),Array("CODE"=>"CML2_AUTO"));
while ($arAuthoItem = $arElement->GetNext())
{
    print_r($arAuthoItem);
} 
Если делать в обратную сторону, то фильтр работает

Comment: А покажите пример -- что внутри `$arFilt` получается? Возможно, там в AND получились взаимоисключающие значения. Ну и, опять же, если там два элемента AND подряд (что while) может обеспечить, то это Битрикс уже не скушает.

И хочется предостеречь: `=PROPERTY_736.XML_ID` -- дорога в ад на сколько-нибудь больших каталогах. Эта конструкция заставляет конструктор запросов делать внутренний `SELECT`, который в конце концов убьет ваш сервер БД.

Comment: @AndrewNikolsky, cпасибо за понимание. Я просто не понимаю документацию -связанные элементы, там написано сделать `=PROPERTY_736.XML_ID`

Comment: @AndrewNikolsky, cпасибо за понимание. Я просто не понимаю документацию -связанные элементы, там написано сделать `=PROPERTY_736.XML_ID` "Можно выбрать и значения свойств элементов по значениям свойства типа "Привязка к элементам". Для этого необходимо указать  PROPERTY_<PROPERTY_CODE>.PROPERTY_<PROPERTY_CODE2>, где PROPERTY_CODE - ID или символьный код свойства привязки, а PROPERTY_CODE2 - свойство указанного в привязке элемента. " (источник http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php)

Вопрос обновила, подскажите, пож-ста.

Comment: Не-не-не, что-то вы совсем не то сделали с запросом.
Первый вариант -- получается массив вложенный в массив и вложенные LOGIC -- лишнее точно, `$arrayMas = array("LOGIC" => "OR");
while($ar_fields = $res1c->GetNext()){
    $arrayMas[]=array("=PROPERTY_736_VALUE"=>$ar_fields['XML_ID'],"=IBLOCK_ID"=>7);
}` -- возможно, так заведется.
Кстати, совет по оформлению: результат `print_r` лучше выдернуть из html-кода страницы, там отступы и переносы строки есть, гораздо проще читать.

Comment: @AndrewNikolsky, после этого запроса все тормознуло-и сайт вообще не открвается... Странно, вывод фильтра работает верно- но не верно работает фильтр в компонентеcatalog.section выдает все товары-(

Comment: А какой в итоге `$arFilt` получился?

Comment: @Andrewus, обновила вопрос. Тут не попишешь код.